# Should my security cameras be raised up under the soffit for weather protection?

Tags: security

I installed 2 outdoor security cameras. But now that I've look at them, I wonder if I should move them under up higher to where the roof meets the wall in order to shield them from the elements.

I've attached pictures. Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could. It's a trade off. If you have them too high, you get stellar footage of your burglars' bald spots. Too low and they can get vandalized.

Comment: Are the cameras rated for outdoor installation?

Answer (score 3):

If those cameras are rated for outdoor, then I wouldn't worry about shielding them from the elements. I would focus instead on capturing an appropriate image. Place them where you feel they will get the picture that you need.

If those cameras are NOT outdoor rated, I would recommend getting an outdoor rated camera. Most people are quick to buy a DIY camera kit but in my experience most of those systems are garbage. If you want to be able to actually make out someones face, then you need to get a very high resolution camera. Most of the people I know have 720p cameras which are good for seeing that something is happening, but not great for picking out fine details like license plate numbers. 1080p Is generally a good bet but for my front door, I use a 1440p camera. When I check on it remotely, I can literally see the ants on the ground in front of my house. I also get EXTREMELY clear images of the solicitors and others that come to my door. If you want some recommendations, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Look like the cameras are outdoor-rated and it's okay at this height as long as you or anyone can't easily grab this and pull it off. Installing security cameras up a bit helps reduce impact and risks from elements and potential grab-and-take.  It's clearly a bullet-shaped camera, moving it a bit higher won't cut down its monitoring areas significantly. My suggestion is to place it beyond reach and make sure the cameras cover the areas that you initially intend to cover.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the camera itself. If it's marked up as an outdoor camera then in most cases they are capable of being directly exposed. The more coverage that can be provided, the longer they could theoretically last - but this is essentially the same as saying that if you leave it in the box it'll never go bad.

They're fine where they are if they are 'outdoor' cameras.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like these cameras are rated for outdoor, so it's okay.

Comment: Why does it seem so? Did you identify the model? Mention of that and/or links to resources would improve this answer.